Add a custom field to WooCommerce settings page with html tag support
I added a field to WooCommerce settings Page(general tab).
But this field does not support html codes and is not saved.
This is my code:
add_filter('woocommerce_general_settings', 'general_settings_shop_map_address');
function general_settings_shop_map_address($settings) {
    $key = 0;

    foreach( $settings as $values ){
        $new_settings[$key] = $values;
        $key++;

        // Inserting array just after the post code in "Store Address" section
        if($values['id'] == 'woocommerce_default_country'){
            $new_settings[$key] = array(
                'title'    => __('store address(map)'),
                'desc'     => __('copy your store google map iframe here'),
                'id'       => 'woocommerce_store_map', // <= The field ID (important)
                'default'  => '',
                'type'     => 'textarea',
                'desc_tip' => true, // or false
            );
            $key++;
        }
    }
    return $new_settings;
}

Also I would like to add another field to support WordPress advanced editor.
can someone help me؟
I put the Google Map iframe code in this field. But it is not saved.

    To allow HTML content in a WooCommerce settings field and ensure it is saved correctly, you need to modify your code to use a text area that supports HTML input. You also need to make sure that the field is properly sanitized and escaped when outputting it. Here is the revised code to achieve this:
    
            add_filter('woocommerce_general_settings', 'general_settings_shop_map_address');
        function general_settings_shop_map_address($settings) {
            $key = 0;
        
            foreach( $settings as $values ){
                $new_settings[$key] = $values;
                $key++;
        
                // Inserting array just after the post code in "Store Address" section
                if($values['id'] == 'woocommerce_default_country'){
                    $new_settings[$key] = array(
                        'title'    => __('Store Address (Map)'),
                        'desc'     => __('Copy your store Google Map iframe here'),
                        'id'       => 'woocommerce_store_map', // <= The field ID (important)
                        'default'  => '',
                        'type'     => 'textarea',
                        'desc_tip' => true, // or false
                        'css'      => 'width:500px;height:150px;', // Adjust width and height as needed
                    );
                    $key++;
                }
            }
            return $new_settings;
        }
        
        // Save the setting value
        add_action('woocommerce_update_options_general', 'save_general_settings_shop_map_address');
        function save_general_settings_shop_map_address() {
            woocommerce_update_option('woocommerce_store_map');
        }
        
        // Allow HTML content in the field
        add_filter('woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_woocommerce_store_map', 'allow_html_in_store_map', 10, 3);
        function allow_html_in_store_map($value, $option, $raw_value) {
            return wp_kses_post($raw_value);
        }

After adding this code to your theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin, you can enter HTML content (like a Google Map iframe) in the new "Store Address (Map)" field on the WooCommerce General settings page. The HTML content will be saved and displayed correctly.


Thanks for your reply. I tested the code. But an error occurred while saving the settings.(Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function woocommerce_update_option() in)
